# Initialize global array of struct with tree in C

Tags: c, arrays, menu, tree

I'm trying to build tree menu structure.

I declared item as:

```
typedef struct menu_item_struct menu_item;
typedef int (*menu_action) (menu_item *item);
typedef bool (*menu_is_selected) (menu_item *item);

struct menu_item_struct{
    char *text;
    menu_action action;
    menu_is_selected is_selected;
    int subitems_count;
    int id;
    menu_item *subitems;
    menu_item *parent;
};
```

First I tried this code and it worked fine:

```
menu_item main_menu = {
    .text = "Top level",
    .action = 0,
    .parent = 0,
    .id     = 0,
    .subitems_count = 3,
    .subitems = &(menu_item[3])
    {
        {
            .text = " ..",
            .action = 0,
            .parent = 0,
            .id     = 0,
            .subitems_count = -1,
            .subitems = 0
        },
        {
            .text = "Subitem 1 level 1",
            .action = 0,
            .parent = 0,
            .id     = 0,
            .subitems_count = 2,
            .subitems = &(menu_item[2])
            {
                {
                    .text = " ..",
                    .action = 0,
                    .parent = 0,
                    .id     = 0,
                    .subitems_count = -1,
                    .subitems = 0
                },
                {
                    .text = "Sub 1 item level 2",
                    .action = 0,
                    .parent = 0,
                    .id     = 0,
                    .subitems_count = 0,
                    .subitems = 0
                }
            }           
        },
        {
            .text = "Subitem 1 level 1",
            .action = 0,
            .parent = 0,
            .id     = 0,
            .subitems_count = -1,
            .subitems = 0
        }
    }
};
```

That's ok for small menu. But for large I tried to split it to several variables. E.g. The "Back" item is present in all sub menues. So I declared it as separate variable:

```
menu_item menu_back = {
    .text = " ..",
    .action = 0,
    .parent = 0,
    .id     = 0,
    .subitems_count = -1,
    .subitems = NULL
};
```

So now when I try that

```
menu_item main_menu = {
    .text = "Menu",
    .action = 0,
    .parent = 0,
    .id     = 0,
    .subitems_count = 1,
    .subitems = &(menu_item[1]) {
        menu_back
    }
};
```

I get "Initialization variable is not a constant".

I just wonder what is the best way to build constant static menu tree?

Comment: Of course is not. But I do not understand your question. Your first declaration is not constant, but the initialisers are constant in the compiler understanding. The second one is not valid in the global / static scope.

Comment: Question is how to make second one valid in global scope. 
Or any other approach to build large multilevel menu

Comment: You can't use variables to initialize global/static variables. C does not allow this as global/static variables are initialised prior to main program start and that initialisation requires constant values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have found out you cannot use content of a variable to initialize static variable. But you can use address of an variable to initialize static variable. In other words, create list of *pointers* to objects, rather than direct list of objects.

However, you'll soon find that this is rather clumsy to maintain.  You'll have lot of variables which you take address of. If you ever have to change `menu_item_struct` definition, you have to edit all initializations by hand.  So, from experience, **avoid doing this in pure C**. Instead:

1. Define menu in your favorite hierarchial text file format (JSON, XML, ...).
2. Use your favorite scripting language (Python, ...) to read text file, and then write out C file which contains menu variables.
3. Compile and link generated C file with you other project files.

Comment: Thanks. That could be a solution